# How to call a REST API service through Vue JS

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I am creating a blog website using Vue JS and Django Rest Framework.

I have a submit Button in Vue JS which should pass text input to Django, How can I do that ?

The POST API link is in localhost:8000/api/post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this with axios

```
var url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/post';
var data = new FormData;
data.append('name','Jane Doe');
axios.post(url,data).then(response => {
  // success
}).catch(thrown => {
  // error
});
```